# Could not load System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt

Tags: azure-web-app-service, nuget-package, octopus-deploy

I have an asp.net MVC app that utilizes owin json web tokens. I have been deploying this app via the Kudu github integration, and the app works fine.

However, I would like to move to deploy via octopus. I am able to create the nuget package needed to deploy and the package is showing as successfully deployed by my octopus server.

Here is where things get weird:

After I deploy via octopus, I am getting the following exception:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

**TL;DR:** why is it that I can run the program fine when deploying via Kudu, but not from a nuget package?

below are some additional details:

**MyApp.nuspec:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
    <id>MyApp</id>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <authors>John Smith</authors>
    <owners>MyCompany</owners>
    <projectUrl>https://github.com/myCompany/MyApp</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/297/297568.svg</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <releaseNotes>Intital Release</releaseNotes>
    <description>MyApp deployment package</description>
    <tags>web app myapp</tags>
    </metadata> </package>
```

**packages.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.7" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="FontAwesome" version="4.7.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.16.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.8" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.0.7" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions" version="1.0.4.403061554" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.4.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="4.0.4.403061554" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Serialization.Json" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Text.RegularExpressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

dependentAssembly section of my web.config:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.8.0" newVersion="2.0.8.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.3.0.0" newVersion="2.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.40306.1554" newVersion="4.0.40306.1554" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.40306.1554" newVersion="1.0.40306.1554" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.1" newVersion="4.1.1.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Answer (score 1):

> why is it that I can run the program fine when deploying via Kudu, but not from a nuget package?

When deploy your web application via Kudu, msbuild will run on Kudu and build the web application on kudu side. It will restore the packages which referenced by your web application. For more information, please check [this document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment#aspnet-web-application-projects-wap).

If we deploy your web application from a NuGet package, we need to publish our web application to a local folder and package the published files to a NuGet package. It means we build your web application on our local and use the original packages. That's the difference between deploying via Kudu and nuget package.

You could clear and restore the packages on your local to fix this issue.

Based on the exception message, the issue is related to the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt package. We can also modify the bindingRedirect section of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt dependentAssembly in web.config as following to solve this issue.

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.40306.1554" newVersion="4.0.40306.1554" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: I already have that dependentAssembly tag in my webconfig, and I have cleared my cache of packages on my build server, and yet I am still getting this problem. this did not work for me.

Comment: Is your web application worked fine on your local and only can't work after published to Azure? If yes, I suggest you download the web configuration file from kudu after you published and compare to local to check whether the configuration file has been modified by octopus.